# CSS Fixed position menu - scrolling issue when resizing the browser

Tags: html, css

I've a fixed position navigation menu. It allows scrolling the list items when the browser height is small, but for some reason the last item is always off the screen.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw9LW/)

HTML

```
<div>Header</div>
<ul>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>Page 3</li>
    <li>Page 4</li>
    <li>Page 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    width: 50%;
    color: white;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    position: fixed;
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 250px;
}
li {
    min-height: 50px; 
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: auto;
}
li:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
@media (max-height: 300px){
    ul {
        overflow: scroll;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `ul` in the css, change `height:100%` to:

```
width: calc(100% - 60px);
```

It works because of the div interfering with the fixed position of your `ul`.

If you're big on browser support, you could also do:

```
padding-right: 60px;
width: 50%;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

which will not work on IE5.5 (hehehe), though, so you could *also* do

```
width: expression(50% - 60px);
```

(which would distort it a bit)
But the funny thing is, you could do *all at the same time!  (In the order `expression, calc, paddingWidthSizingBox`)*

And if you're worried about the small amount of people still using IE 4 & <, ***<kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>cannot</kbd> <kbd>help</kbd> <kbd>you</kbd> <kbd>there</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>and</kbd> <kbd>nobody</kbd> <kbd>else</kbd> <kbd>can.</kbd>***

<strike>Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hw9LW/1/</strike>

[EDIT]
[Here is the *updated* fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw9LW/2/)

Comment: Thanks! also is the 60px to compensate for the top margin ?

Comment: @RedJohn Yes, and look at my edit, so you can support more browsers.

Comment: @RedJohn I made a small typo, it's width not height!

Comment: Thanks a lot really! As for the browser support, I don't really aim for IE users at all

Comment: @RedJohn Me neither, but 14% is a notable amount.

Comment: It's for a small personal website, IE visitors are like 4% and most of them use IE11/IE10.